# Getting a javascript function which takes 2 php variables as arguments to work

Tags: javascript

I want to make it so that when a user double clicks on a row in a table, it will check two variables `($row["CustomerRequestID"]` and `$row["JobID"])` and then, if JobID is equal to null, open a new window.  This is what I have so far

```
echo '<tr ondblclick="workStatusDoubleClick(\''.str_replace("'", "\\'", $row["CustomerRequestID"]).'\', \''.str_replace("'", "\\'", $row["JobID"]).'\')" >';

function workStatusDoubleClick(value,jobID) {
  if (jobID == "") {
    window.open("quoteRecord.php?quoteID="+value, "_blank", "toolbar=0, location=0, menubar=0, width=900, height=700, scrollbars=yes" );
  }
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You've declared the function `workStatusDoubleClick` as a PHP function, and you're trying to access it as Javascript code. That's the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (avoid complex cod):

```
<?php
    $val1 = str_replace("'", "\\'", $row["JobID"]);
    $val2 = str_replace("'", "\\'", $row["CustomerRequestID"]);
?>
<tr ondblclick="workStatusDoubleClick('<?php echo $val1;?>', '<?php echo $val2;?>');">

<script>
    function workStatusDoubleClick(value,jobID)
    {
        if (jobID == "")
        {
            window.open("quoteRecord.php?quoteID="+value, "_blank", "toolbar=0, location=0, menubar=0, width=900, height=700, scrollbars=yes" );
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are getting a JavaScript error, best way to debug is to see what is generated by the PHP

for your tr assign a id eg:

```
    <tr id="mytr" ..... >
```

In JavaScript add the following line:

```
    alert(document.getElementById("mytr").parentNode.innerHTML);
```

The alert will show you what is the generated output and it might help you in understanding further.

Answer (score 0):

Put additional parameter to "tr"'s attribute

For example

```
<tr CustomerRequestID="number1" JobID="number2" id="trnumber3">....</tr>

$("trnumber3").click(function()
{
     if ($(this).attr("CustomerRequestID")==... or $(this).attr("JobID")==..)
          doSomething();
});
```